# routes on server don't display properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have models that belong to a "parent" model.
in the console, the relationship works fine,
but when trying to display in the browser it fails

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api  do
    namespace :v1   do

      resources :parents do
        resources :siblings, :path => "children"
      end

      resources :siblings do
        resources :milestones
      end

      resources :siblings do
        resources :kind_words
      end

      resources :siblings do
        resources  :nice_deeds
      end

    end
  end
end
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjIOk.png

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext. Images of plaintext are not appropriate on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have `kind_words`, not `kindwords`. Try go to `api/v1/sibilings/2/kind_words`

You can even change that part of the path for that resource like this

```
resources :kind_words, path: :kindwords
```

and try that same path you were using